# Dangling modifier

Tags: syntactic-analysis

My reviewer revised the sentence

"a high level of social distancing can result in economic loss **by** discontinuation of business activities"

as

"a high level of social distancing can result in economic loss **because of the** discontinuation of business activities"

I don't think the revision is logically sound. "because of" is supposed to introduce the cause of something. But in this context, the cause of what? of economic loss? The cause of economic loss is social distancing, as "result in" indicates (the paper is about the effects of social distancing, which has therefore a stronger causal bearing). Am I correct?

Comment: I'd use 'due to' (and include the 'the'), but can't see a vast problem with either of the other two suggestions here. The economic loss is caused by the discontinuation of business activities which is itself caused by the high level of social distancing.

Comment: ***through*** and ***via*** would be tolerable alternative preposition-based linking terms here. It's POB

Comment: If we move the phrase to a fronting position: *"By discontinuation of business activities*, a high level of social distancing can result in economic loss” -- *"Because of the discontinuation of business activities,* a high level of social distancing can result in economic loss.” Neither seems to be correct/idiomatic. It needs restructuring: --*"A discontinuation (you may mean “disruption”) of business activities caused by a high level of social distancing can result in economic loss.”*

Comment: Why use a nominalization when the active verb is available? _by discontinuing business activities_ does the job with fewer and better morphemes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your suggestion is closer to the intended meaning. "by" is ambiguous, as "by X" may imply that  X is the agent or the means.